# Command to publish Jacoco code coverage to sonar

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I can see different maven configuration and commands to publish Jacoco coverage to Sonar but is there any command without maven, ant etc which can publish Jacoco coverage to Sonar?

I've a Jacoco coverage report file to publish.

Answer (score 0):

To include Jacoco coverage add to your sonar-scanner invocation `-Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=/path/to/report`. See https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/ for more information.